# Reading datasets on kaggle vs collab gives different shapes

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I tried to read the shape of the dataset on kaggle and it shows

```
df_tr.shape # 35,33,286
(3533286, 9)
```

and in collab, it shows

```
df_tr.shape 
(71188, 9)
```

I am not sure why this much difference. Could someone please let me know? The dataset I am trying to read it in the kaggle.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mkechinov/ecommerce-events-history-in-cosmetics-shop?select=2019-Dec.csv

Comment: did you read the correct csv in both situations?

Comment: I found the mistake, So i was doing a step after I read the pdf like df_tr.head() so when I read the shape of it. It was showing less. Now it shows fine

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the data like this

```
df_tr = pd.read_csv('2019-Dec.csv')
df_tr.head()
```

so when I ran the below step

```
df_tr.shape
```

it shows fewer records. when I removed df_tr.head() then it shows the proper count as the one in kaggle.

Comment: this is so strange.. it should not behave like this, no?

Comment: Yes it shouldn't but collab is annoying sometimes.

Comment: I also think the another reason could be that I did not wait until the collab completely loaded the dataset. So, I read half of it.